# Area between the following curves: $y=\log[x+1], y=e^{-x}-1, x=1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals, area

I need to find the area between the following curves:

> $$y=\log[x+1]$$ 
>   $$y=e^{-x}-1$$
>   $$x=1$$

By drawing on the Cartesian plane I found out that I need the intersection between the first and the second to set the definite integral.
However I don't know how to solve the following equality:
$$\log[x+1]=e^{-x}-1$$

Where I am wrong? Is there a easier method?
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

By plotting the curves, guessing or asking [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log(x%2B1)%3Dexp(%E2%88%92x)%E2%88%921) you will see that $\log(x+1)=e^{-x}-1$ has only one solution, which is $x=0$. You are on the right way.